# PHP and Javascript code needed to check if form fields are not empty

Tags: php, javascript

Javascript needed to prevent form submit if any of field is empty. all my form fields start names start with name=add[FieldName] those are the fields that need checking.

PHP, backend check before submiting to database double check to make sure all $POST are not empty

Comment: Don't worry about the JavaScript, just make sure you have the checks working on the server side. Any fool can easily turn off JavaScript to get past the client side checks.

Comment: This seems more like a request then a question.

Comment: @animuson It's more user-friendly to have an error pop-up immediately than wait for the server to come up with an error response.

@Mike That's the exact same thing I thought.

Comment: @animuson and @Arda Xi - I think the happy medium is that they shouldn't _rely_ on JavaScript validation as that is insecure and easily circumvented, but it is nonetheless good to worry about usability, which is best attained by adding JavaSript, _in addition_ to the server-side checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to write the javascript, but here's some PHP.

```
$valid = true;
foreach($_POST as $key)
{
    if(!isset($key))
    {
        $valid = false;
    }
}

if(!$valid)
{
    header("Location: /path/to/form");
}
```

Comment: You meant to use `isset` not `unset`.

Comment: Also, `$key` would be better named `$value`; to save time, why not just `header(Location:...)` and `exit` or `die` as soon as `$ valid` becomes false?

Comment: thanks for the code Josh. Sorry for requesting code, I know it wasn't really a question. Stackoverflow seems to be the best place for fast and reliable help. this is the final code I used. <code> foreach($_POST['add'] as $value) { if(isset($value)) { $valid = false; $err .= 'please fill in all fields'; $en['reg_error'] = '<div class=err style="color: #FF0000;"><b>'._error.': '.$err.'</b></div><br>'; load_template('modules/members/templates/reg_gender.tpl'); } } <code>

Comment: @Richard: Nice spot, yes I did.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a javascript function you can use. Just call it for each id belonging to the fields in question.

```
function isEmpty(field_id) {
  var empty = false;
  if (document.getElementById(field_id).value == null)
    empty = true;

  if (document.getElementById(field_id).value == "")
    empty = true;

  return empty;
}
```

If you have them predictably named, you could call this function in a loop. If, for instance, they were named field1, field2, ..., field23, then you could just have the following in your main code body:

```
for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    var emptyCheck = false;
    if(isEmpty("field"+i)) {
        emptyCheck = true;
        //do whatever you want to do when a value is empty
    }
}
```

Comment: hi jgb146 is there a way to do it for all id fields, so there's not a long list of coding. i have about 23 fields

Comment: I'll edit my response to include some possible code for this.